# Livestamp.js + Moment.js - how to update the time ones every 30 seconds?

Tags: javascript, timestamp, momentjs

I have installed Timestamp+Moments and did a quick setup so it will show `#s`, `#m`, `#h`.

The question is how to stop the counter and only update the times ones per 30 seconds so instead of `1s`/`2s`/`3s`, we'll only see `1s` and the next update will be at `30s` and then `1m`.

CODE:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toISOString();

<span data-livestamp="'+n+'"></span>
```

Comment: You have to show us what you tried.  You cannot just list requirements.

Comment: @MattJohnson the thing is that I don't even know when to setTimeOut, I've lurked both Moment.js and Timestamp.js and I have no idea where to change the updating interval. I just thought somebody used those and can suggest where to set it up.

Comment: You've got multiple questions wrapped into this.  How to format a timestamp for output.  How to update a DOM element periodically on a timer.  How to snap to 30 whole second intervals once you have a working timer.  Also, why would you go from `1s` to `30s`? That's 29 seconds.  And what is `data-livestamp`?  Are you using some JS framework you didn't mention?  There's also so many questions similar to these already, so you really should search/browse more and try something first.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center.

Comment: Also, if your question is specifically about the [Livestamp.js](https://mattbradley.github.io/livestampjs/]) library, you should tag your question with that rather than put it into the title, and be clearer in your question that you're looking for a solution within the scope of that library.  (You may just have better luck asking on the issue tracker for that library also.)